# Create a django queryset for non-database data

Tags: django, django-admin, external, feed

I'm looking for a way to create a simple ModelForm with one drop down list based on an external data feed. The reason I want this is to be able to import data from an external source via django admin.

An example of this could be a model `class BlogPost(models.Model)` with many fields. In the "create new object" in django admin it should only be a single field; a list of post from an external blog. When the user chooses a post in a drop down list and saves the object the save method of `BlogPost` fetches all the relevant data from the feed, sets the appropriate fields in the BlogPost instance and saves it to the database.

I'm stuck at the "fetch external data and present it in django admin" part of this. From what I cal tell the best way to do this, and still be able to use the standard components of django would be to wrap the external feed in a "non-database, custom queryset", and pass it to a `forms.ModelChoiceField`? Is there a simple way to to this?

(I'm not actually creating a blog post stealer. I have a video archive back end that is completely separate from the site I'm creating and I need a user friendly way to import data from it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelChoiceField` is specifically for querysets. If you want to use a non queryset, why not use `ChoiceField` which is for any list of any objects? 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield

Or am I missing something here?

```
mychoices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('external_post', 'External Post'), ('external_post2', 'External Post 2')])
```

You would be free to populate the list from any source you wish!

Comment: I guess I could use a ChoiceField and not a ModelChoiceField as long as the values are evaluated each time the form is rendered. If I say ChoiseField(choices=foo()) than foo will be evaluated one time only and I am not able to pass a function reference ChoiseField(choice=foo) for choices.

Comment: And the solution for that is available [here](http://ilian.i-n-i.org/django-forms-choicefield-with-dynamic-values/) :)

Comment: Yeah, override __init__ for any dynamic form stuff